# Intel graphics drivers on Windows 10 technical preview

Tags: drivers, windows-10-preview

So I was trying out the Windows 10 technical preview build 10074 on my **HP Pavilion 15-p241nd**. I tried installing the Intel Graphics drivers but it keeps showing up this error message,

[image: Error message]

I do understand that the technical preview doesn't support anything yet but after searching online I came across [this](https://communities.intel.com/message/261938) post by *ssn650* on the Intel forums.

> I was able to manually install the Intel HD Graphics drivers by:
>
> - Deleting the reference to Threshold in the configuration file that prevented installation with Windows Technical Preview
> - Modifying the first line in the Windows 8.1 setup section header to [IntelGfx.NTamd64.6.4]
> - Restarting in Windows Troubleshoot mode to allow installation of drivers not digitally signed

These steps aren't very well explained, how would one achieve this?

Comment: When I tried Windows 10 on my laptop, which also has Intel Graphics chipset, I didn't had to install the driver. I simply ran Windows Updates, the  appropriate drivers installed this way.

Comment: @Ob1lan It did do this with the Nvidea driver although no luck with the Intel one.

Comment: The best advice I can give you.  You should wait to install Windows 10 until Windows 10 RTM is released and Intel releases updates to its drivers.  Which part of those instructions are not clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easier to unzip (I use 7-zip to do this) the Intel driver to a folder, then use device manager to install the driver manually.

1. Login with administrator privileges
2. Open Control Panel
3. Open Device Manager
4. Click on "Display adapters"
5. Double click "Intel Graphics" (or similar name)
6. Click on the "Driver" tab
7. Click on "Update Driver" button
8. Click on "Browse my computer for driver software"
9. Click on "Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer"
10. Click on "Have Disk" button
11. Click "Browse"
12. Navigate to the folder that you unzipped the Intel Graphics driver to
13. Navigate to the Graphics sub-folder
14. Double click the igdlh64.inf or igdlh.inf file <-- depends on if you have 32 or 64 bit OS (**Your inf may have a different name**)
15. Click "OK"
16. Click "Next", Driver should now be installing.
17. If successful, click "Close", Reboot.